# Find out max value for each group along with name

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a table Employee whose contents are as below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                       Department                  Salary
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Hemant                      PTS                         100
Gunjan                      PTS                         101
Amol                        ADM                         50
Parthiv                     ADM                         60
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a SINGLE query to display name of highest salary consumer group by PTS.
In other words output of query should be as Gunjan and Parthiv are from different department and earning highest salary in that department.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                       Department                  Salary
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Gunjan                      PTS                         101
Parthiv                     ADM                         60
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below query is working properly

```
SELECT E.Department,MAX(E.Salary) FROM 
Employee E
GROUP BY Department;
```

But how can I select name along with department and Max(Salary)?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMS, this query below will almost work on almost any RDBMS (*but not all I guess*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Employee a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Department, MAX(Salary) Max_Val
            FROM    Employee
            GROUP   BY Department
        ) b ON a.Department = b.Department AND
                a.Salary = b.Max_Val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8605/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║  NAME   ║ DEPARTMENT ║ SALARY ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ Gunjan  ║ PTS        ║    101 ║
║ Parthiv ║ ADM        ║     60 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```